# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException when using explicit wait in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am building a simple script to capture the error message **invalid userid/password** when I give incorrect userid and password and click on submit button.
I am getting `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException` when using explicit wait in my code(below).

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8));

wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions
.TextToBePresentInElementValue(driver.FindElement(By.Id("signInBtn")), "Sign in"));

TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("alert-danger")).Text);
```

I also tried implicit wait `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);` and though the test passes, I cannot see the error message in the test result.
I use `thread.sleep(3000);` and it works like a charm. Test passes and I can see the error message captured in the result.
Why are the other two steps failing ?

Comment: I am not sure why you are waiting for the text to be present in the element. you can just wait for an element to be visible. 
WebElement element = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("signInBtn")));
plus as per your statement if the test case passes then your wait condition is successfully fulfilled.
and you might need to add wait until on error message.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. Actually, I forgot to mention that the value of the button is "Sign In" before I click. Upon clicking, the value changes to "Signing" and later it changes back to "Sign In" once the error message is displayed. So I want the script to wait till the value changes back to "Sign In" so that it can capture the error message. Also I am confused, if thread.sleep(3000); can show the error message captured then why wouldn't the implicit wait step show it though the test runs passed.